# Ubuntu deb install dependency libsdl1.2debian-purgeaudio

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, deb

Good day every one. I have some custom_program.deb file wich working fine on Ubuntu 10.04. When i try install it on later version (like 12.04 or more) i have dependency error about libsdl1.2debian-purgesound.
if i try  `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian-purgesound` it says that package don't available and it's old, and now i should use `liblsd1.2debian` which how i understand already include purgesound.
The question is how to tell my .deb file about that, because if i `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian` i have the same dependency error about libsdl1.2debian-purgesound. Or how i can install old version of Ubuntu (10.04) i try different iso but with the same result while instalation i have (grub-pc package error) i looking about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).Thank you for helping me if u would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solve this problem quite easy. replace source list in /etc/apt/source.list with old release sources list.
`sudo apt-get update` and now i can install old packages that i was need.
Hope it could help somebody.